# Typescript error : Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm new to typescript and it's a hell trying to make some code works, can someone help me  solve this ts error.

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ 'sections.hero': ({ sectionData, key }: props) => Element; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ 'sections.hero': ({ sectionData, key }: props) => Element; }'.

my code :

```
type sectionDataProps = {
  sectionData: {
    __component: string;
  };
};

// Map Strapi sections to section components
const sectionComponents = {
  'sections.hero': Hero,
};

// Display a section individually
const Section = ({ sectionData }: sectionDataProps) => {
  // Prepare the component
  const SectionComponent = sectionComponents[sectionData.__component];

  if (!SectionComponent) {
    return null;
  }

  // Display the section
  return <SectionComponent data={sectionData} />;
};

// Display the list of sections
const Sections = (props: { sections: [] }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {/* Show the actual sections */}
      {props.sections.map((section) => (
        <Section
          sectionData={section}
          key={`${section.__component}${section.id}`}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Sections;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typescript you are not allowed to access properties that may not exist. That means that when have a type like `{ a: number }`, that you may only access the `a` property. Checking the `b` property would be a type error because it does not exist.

---

So you have this type for the key:

```
__component: string;
```

And this type for the object that key is expected to be on:

```
const sectionComponents = {
  'sections.hero': Hero,
};
```

Which means that only one single string is allowed for this operation:

```
sectionComponents[sectionData.__component]
```

And that string is `'sections.hero'` any other string will not be allowed.

You can fix this a few ways.

---

First, you could change the type of the `__component` property to be:

```
type sectionDataProps = {
  sectionData: {
    __component: keyof typeof sectionComponents;
  };
};
```

Now any `string` is not a valid value. The strings *must* be keys of the `sectionComponents` object.

And the rest of you code works without modification. [See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

---

If you didn't want to change the props types, you have to change the logic of your function to make sure that you do not access a property that may not exist.

```
// Display a section individually
const Section = ({ sectionData }: sectionDataProps) => {
  // Prepare the component
  if (sectionData.__component in sectionComponents) {
      const key = sectionData.__component as keyof typeof sectionComponents
      const SectionComponent = sectionComponents[key];
      return <SectionComponent data={sectionData} />;
  }

  return null
};
```

Here we use an `in` check to see if a property exists on that object. Then it should be be safe to manually cast that to `keyof typeof sectionComponents` to let typescript know that we are certifying this operation as safe.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=76&pln=22&pc=43#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTMBXAOw2AmrgAkkcAKMHMAZwC5EkaaABMAPNxhRg1AOYAaODQDW1CAHdqAPgCUcAN6k4RuERiUojUZtEB6TaQC+5GAE8wSON0Ex61ACIoMCgAClzccAC8+oae3r4BQfwGxnAA+qlC4AxI1DD8ElKyANwxDiVl5DY2cACyKGBwAMqS9cCxdAzhMBDtPgxwmZDUOTDcpELUEr2+AMK4QyPhUckEXh2TAHQAFqwQ+PwsOHKOJaRVcH7A3GAANigucCjT-dLCwABuwMKUKDc3LuNOvBGnF+lE2Hpnv5Ak8HPlQdCgqEIDxdBFNNEjOdQkgwCgiHAYDsBvNsrkYsBMHA2Gs+oiUBt0oMyfBpFC5llhrluLoVikJlMlEgHlFafEYYyMqSufAUOEhS4IFTXO4lezpYsYvygU0ERyFrlIurOYsANoKgC6JRSRlM5ksIPW+pZcGEMIiejFDASKAccDs1rgThidoscGolD+J0q1Uu1zuDyJHhuV3gaq9k0Bk2BCKW1M4KL4+ihRdNFqDaIxK1DjDYWrgVnrRj0NgAVE0tupCcT0GZfiW4K2bE4bfoCzwNhnuBsQPU2DSEZXqU3jKJHXSVykMz6PRmR6PjAqPQADAAknoRkuZMoc54zGy+DmP+9HdhX2m0L4bb6M2nKpyQAAPSBYFdJBMBQSMc3WbgiiAA)